Why will mass $m$ stop moving in this question?
The question says:

Mass $m$ carrying a charge $q$ is suspended from a string and placed in a uniform horizontal electric field of intensity $E$. Find the angle between the string and the vertical in the equilibrium position.

I know how to solve this, but my question is how can we prove that the string stops moving at some point? (I think we should prove work done by electric field and earth are equal to each other in the final form ,so velocity is zero)
My second question is, if there is friction in the system, some heat energy will be produced after the string gets to its final form (because the movement of string and mass m is associated with sliding friction and some of their kinetic energy will convert to heat).But the final form is still the same, which means potential energy of the system in its final form, isn't up to existence of friction in the system. How does it match conservation of energy ?

If the net force on the mass is zero it will not be accelerating.
What happens when you displace a simple pendulum from its static equilibrium position and release it?
The pendulum (system) oscillates about the static equilibrium position with ever decreasing amplitude, eventually stopping at the equilibrium position due to the frictional forces acting on it.
The proof of this is akin to the analysis you did for damped simple harmonic motion.
A similar thing would happen to the pendulum in your example after the electric field is switched on with the mass initially oscillating about the static equilibrium position and eventually stopping there.
This pendulum system would have more gravitational potential energy than when the was no electric field as the mass is higher and that extra gravitational potential energy comes from the work done by the electric field whiuch produces an external force on the system.
